# Access writing violation when returning a 2d array from function in C

Tags: arrays, c

I'm getting this exception whenever I try to return a 2d array from a specific function.

```
Exception thrown at 0x00D7572A in game_of_life.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000A.
```

I did something similar right above it, which compiles perfectly fine for some reason. I've tried stepping through the code with breakpoints, but it seems that the only issue is in main(), where I try to assign the values from Here's the relevant code:

```
#define board_size 10

typedef struct {        // any given board, easier to pass into functions like this
    int b[board_size][board_size];
}board;


void main() {
    board test_board = rand_state();
    render(test_board);

    board test_count = count(test_board);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    render(test_count);
}

board count (board curr) {
    board count = dead_state();

    for (int i = 0; i < board_size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board_size; j++) {
            count.b[i][j] = adjacent_to(curr.b, i, j);
        }
    }
}

int xadd(int i, int a) {
    i += a;
    while (i < 0) {
        i += board_size;        // using the board_size as an offset
    }
    while (i >= board_size) {
        i -= board_size;        
    }
    return i;
}

int yadd(int i, int a) {
    i += a;
    while (i < 0) {
        i += board_size;
    }
    while (i >= board_size) {
        i -= board_size;
    }
    return i;
}

int adjacent_to(int board[][board_size], int i, int j) {
    int k, l, no_live;
    no_live = 0;

    // go around the cell
    for (k = -1; k <= 1; k++) {
        for (l = -1; l <= 1; l++) {
            // only count if at least one of k, l isn't zero

        if (k || l) {
            if (board[xadd(i, k)][yadd(j, l)]) {
                no_live++;
            }
        }
        }
    }

    return no_live;
}
```

Comment: There's no `return` statement in `count()`. You should have gotten a warning about that when compiling.

Comment: It should end with `return count;`

Comment: May be overkill here, but related to @Barmar's comment on compiler warnings: read [Getting the maximum out of your C compiler, for security](https://airbus-seclab.github.io/c-compiler-security/). Most notably (if using gcc): `-Wall -Wextra` and optionally `-Werror`.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, that's exactly it. I can't believe i didn't spot that, thank you